# Unable to change UEFI boot order on Windows dual boot computer

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I’ve just installed Ubuntu on an old Windows laptop. On boot it always boots into Windows. If I go into the UEFI boot configuration then the options are Windows, Ubuntu, and EFI.But there doesn’t seem to be any way to change the order - plus and minus don’t do anything. I’ve tried Haslio easyUEFI, but can’t get changes to persist. If I hit F10 during boot it takes me into BIOS settings but doesn’t let me change the boot to Ubuntu, only to change between drives, USB, etc. So at the moment my only way into Ubuntu is to boot Windows, go through the settings | update and security | recovery | restart now | troubleshoot | advanced options | UEFI firmware settings | restart | boot device options | OS boot manager (UEFI) ubuntu sequence, which takes about a quarter of an hour (I said it was an old laptop) - unacceptable, as I want Ubuntu to be my primary OS. How can I get it to offer me a choice of which system to boot? (Secure boot is off, by the way.) Thanks.

Comment: With HP you have to use HP's system settings. Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2

Comment: Sounds like an UEFI problem, not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: That was it! Well spotted/guessed that it's a HP! I can't mark it as the answer, though, because it's a comment, not a reply. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP seems to be the only brand that does not support efibootmgr changes to boot order. Grub install uses efibootmgr to change to make Ubuntu first in boot order. Something in HP always changes it back to the "Windows" UEFI boot entry.

HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings

In the UEFI settings, should be a boot tab to allow you to change boot order.

With HP you have to use HP's system settings. Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2

I do not have HP, but from above page:

Power on and press F10 to access HP UEFI set up System Configuration > Boot Options > OS Boot manager (under UEFI Boot Order)

If Ubuntu is the first option, then the PC will boot Ubuntu first. You can change the default with F5 and F6 keys.